# Is it possible to make icons clickable from a background image?

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, background, icons, clickable

I'm relatively new to app development and working with Android Studio and layouts. I'm in the process of designing my app and have encountered an issue. I have the design for a ListItem for a ListView where the player's name and 2 icons (Edit and Delete) should be displayed. So, when the user adds a player, the entries should be displayed like that.

My problem now is: How can I best implement the design in XML to achieve the desired functionality?

[ListItem Design, created with Figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXLKx.png)

I thought one could design the whole thing as a button in XML, which then receives this design as a background. But then the question is, how can I make the icon clickable?

Or is there any better way to do this, that i might miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - don't use `ListView` - it has lots of problems. Use `RecyclerView`.

There are multiple ways to do this. You can use this one, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text_end"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/text_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="your drawable path goes here"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_end"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="your drawable path goes here"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/edit" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Don't forget to add path to your image in `ImageView` `src` attribute.

Then in your ViewHolder you can find and set `onClickListener` on each `ImageView`

Comment: Thank you that worked for me just fine :)